# Find magnitude pole of an array

Tags: java, algorithm

Please review this code, considering I put emphasis on constraining space complexity at the expense of execution speed (accepting additional branching).

- Can you see cases that prove the algorithm incorrect?
- Could you improve its execution speed without increasing space complexity?
- Could you make it more readable?

Method signature from Codility (i.e. strange capitalised parameter name).

Definition of "magnitude pole": available online (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397637/interview-find-magnitude-pole-in-an-array)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MagnitudePole {
  public int solution(int[] A) {
    final int notFound = -1;
    final int minimumArrayLength = 2;
    if (A.length < minimumArrayLength) {
      return notFound;
    }
    int magnitudePole = 0;
    boolean isPoleValid = true;
    int highestSeen = A[magnitudePole];
    for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
      final int currentValue = A[i];
      if (currentValue < A[magnitudePole]) {
        isPoleValid = false;
      } else if (currentValue > A[magnitudePole]) {
        if (currentValue > highestSeen && !isPoleValid) {
          isPoleValid = true;
          magnitudePole = i;
        }
      } else {
        if (currentValue < highestSeen) {
          isPoleValid = false;
        } else {
          isPoleValid = true;
          magnitudePole = i;
        }
      }
      highestSeen = Math.max(currentValue, highestSeen);
    }
    return isPoleValid ? magnitudePole : notFound;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Style

```
final int notFound = -1;
final int minimumArrayLength = 2;
```

These two fields can be better placed as `private static final` fields, instead of inside the method. On a related note, you may also want to consider turning this into an "utility class" and have the method as `static` too:

```
public class MagnitudePole {

    private static final int notFound = -1;
    private static final int minimumArrayLength = 2;

    private MagnitudePole() {
        // empty
    }

    // using an arguably better-sounding name... MagnitudePole.solveFor(int[])
    public static int solveFor(int[] A) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

<s>For the `currentValue > A[magnitudePole]` `else-if` condition, you can join that with the inner `if`</s>:

There's a bug here all right... The `else` should only be done on the original outer condition, so if the inner `if`conditions fail it shouldn't reach there. Slightly edited the code block so as not to invalidate the comments on this part. :)

```
if (currentValue < A[magnitudePole]) {
    isPoleValid = false;
} else if (currentValue > A[magnitudePole] && currentValue > highestSeen && !isPoleValid) {
    isPoleValid = true;
    magnitudePole = i;
} else {
    /* this should only be reached when
        currentValue <= A[magnitudePole],
        bug in preceding else-if! */
}
```

Finally, in the `else` part, you can also re-order the conditions around as such:

```
} else {
    isPoleValid = currentValue >= highestSeen;
    if (isPoleValid) {
      magnitudePole = i;
    }
}
```

## Logic + unit testing

You perform a check for the array to contain at least two elements, which means single-element arrays are conveniently bypassed. Do you actually want to consider them as magnitude poles, since all the LHS and RHS elements ("none", or \$\emptyset\$) [are equal to it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)? :)

I will also suggest writing unit tests as a means of documenting what are the expected outputs for various inputs - valid, invalid, and edge cases in all. The slight benefit is that you can safely optimize your logic later on, and have a safety mechanism to ensure the modifications still work per expectation.

Comment: Thanks for your review :) I prefer your merged `if` formulation; I should turn on static code analysis before posting next time, as tools like PMD are good at highlighting opportunities for _simplified conditionals_. Your re-ordered `else` is way better and I should have spotted the _code smell_ of the repeated isPoleValid = ... You have a fine eye for detail, I appreciate that. Re: logic -> I just made that assumption based on the Codility problem description, notice the "minimumArrayLength" boundary. I agree though that one should think about edge cases deeply, beyond the common code paths..

Comment: Re: unite testing -> you know I just rewrote that `if` as you did and it is giving me different results for input values: 1) [1, 3, 2]; 2) [1, 3, 5, 4]; 3) [1, 2, 4, 3]. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, thinking about it, I think your "merged logic" is incorrect. It looked promising, but it has a bug :( You don't want to "fall through" the `else` if the second part of the condition fails, right?

Comment: @Maroloccio thanks for spotting the bug! Updated my answer... Another reason why unit testing is important. :D

Comment: Actually, I do have unit testing for this and... that's what caught the anomaly in the test cases I highlighted. I should have included it for clarity, review and regression avoidance, you were right.